# Getting the value of an element added after DOM has loaded with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

On a site i'm working on, I have an ajax call that returns a chunk of code that is then inserted into a div tag. In this chunk of code, I have a `select`, hidden `input` and a `button`. When the user clicks that button, I need to get the value of the `select` and the `input`.

My button did not work at first and I cured that with using `.on()` to get the code below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(document).on('click','#addBtn', function(){
       var qty = $('#qtySelect').val();
       var itemID = $('#itemName').val();

        alert(qty + "    " + itemID);
    });

    $('#genStuff').click(function(){
        $('#newContent').append('<div id="infoRight">Quantity: <select name="qty"><option value="1">1</option></select><input type="hidden" name="itemID" value="1000"><button id="addBtn">Add to Cart</button></div>');
    });

});
```

The button now works, but I get `undefined` for the values.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1mmueLot/) of the problem.

From googling, I keep getting results dealing with `click` events and to use `.on()` but that's not helping me get the values. I'm assuming I have to let the DOM know the elements are there somehow, but i'm not sure how.

EDIT: I made a stupid mistake due to having stared at my code for way too long. I forgot to put the id's on select and input.

Comment: what do you want to get with itemID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [id selectors](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). when you use a `#`, then jquery searches for an element with that id.

You need to use another [selector](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) or change the html.

Add `id="qtySelect"` to the select element that you are adding to the dom, like this

```
$('#newContent').append('<div id="infoRight">Quantity: <select name="qty" id="qtySelect">.....
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> As you are appending multiple elements, you should not have ID selector as you should not have multiple IDs in same Document. I have changed it to class and Every time I am finding the form elements which are withing the parent of clicked Button

```
<button id="genStuff">Click me!</button>
    <div id="newContent"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $(document).on('click', '.addBtn', function()
            {
                var parent=$(this).parents('.infoRight');
                var qty=parent.find('[name="qty"]').val();
                var itemID=parent.find('[name="itemID"]').val();
                alert(qty + "    " + itemID);
            });
            $('#genStuff').click(function()
            {
                $('#newContent').append('<div class="infoRight">Quantity: <select name="qty"><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option></select><input type="hidden" name="itemID" value="1000"><button class="addBtn">Add to Cart</button></div>');
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please include an explanation of how this code is different than the OP's code, and why this solves the problem without introducing new problems.